# Python curried function with variable number of arguments

Tags: python, functional-programming, currying

Given `n`, I'd like to make a function which takes in `n` elements and returns them as a list. One way to do this:

```
def g(n):
  def f(*l):
    assert len(l) == n
    return l
  return f
```

My problem: I'd like the return function to be [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

The result would work something like this, but for all `n`:

```
def g(n):
    if n == 1: return lambda i: [i]
    if n == 2: return lambda i1: lambda i2: [i1, i2]
    if n == 3: return lambda i1: lambda i2: lambda i3: [i1, i2, i3]
    ...
```

My first approach went something like this:

```
def g(n):
    if n == 1: return lambda i: [i]
    return lambda i: g(n-1) + [i]
```

This doesn't work: `g(n-1)` returns a function, so it can't be added to the list. Is there a fix?

It seems like I need to somehow "pass the input" along to `g(n-1)`, get the output of `g(n-1)`, and tack on `[i]`, but I don't know how to "pry open" `g(n-1)` to do the tacking on, while maintaining the correct input type for it.

I tried googling currying in python, but I only got some basic examples. I am new to functional programming, so sorry if my terminology is lacking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with this:

```py
def f(n, prev=None):
    if prev is None:
        prev = []

    if n == 1:
        return lambda x: prev + [x]
    else:
        return lambda x: f(n-1, prev=prev + [x])

# f(3) creates list with length 3
# other calls append one element to the list, until length 3 is reached
assert f(3)(1)(2)(3) == [1,2,3]
```